# Nomenclature entry in TOC not indented like a chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, nomencl

I am trying to use the `nomencl` package in my report to generate a list of symbols. The `nomencl` package has an option that allows the TOC to print an entry for the Nomenclature.

I am also using the KOMA class, passing an option `toc=indentunnumbered` which gives me the capability to add unnumbered chapters that are indented as though there *were* indented (with `\addchap`. The problem here is that when I use `\printnomenclature`, it does not follow the option that was passed to KOMA.

**Qn:** How can I get the Nomenclature entry in TOC to be indented as though it were numbered, so that it fits in nicely with the rest of my TOC entries?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\KOMAoptions{toc = indentunnumbered}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \printnomenclature

    \addchap{Using \texttt{addchap}} 
    Test
    \chapter{Normal chapter}
    Test

    \nomenclature{$c$}{speed}
\end{document}
```

[image: nomenclature in TOC]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be to patch usage of `\addxcontentsline` instead of `\addcontentsline` into `nomencl.sty`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\thenomenclature}{\addcontentsline}{\addxcontentsline}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\thenomenclature}{\addcontentsline}{\addxcontentsline}{}{}
\KOMAoptions{toc=indentunnumbered}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \printnomenclature

    \addchap{Using \texttt{addchap}} 
    Test
    \chapter{Normal chapter}
    Test

    \nomenclature{$c$}{speed}
\end{document}
```

The patch is needed two times as shown above. The result would be:

[image]

A more complex solution would be to patch `nomencl.sty` to use `\addchap` if available instead of `\chapter*` and `\addcontentsline`.

A very easy solution will be available with [KOMA-Script v3.23](http://www.komascript.de/node/2098). Since [KOMA-Script Prerelease v3.23.2615](http://www.komascript.de/current) it is enough to load package `scrhack` to not only solve the issue but also have automatic running heads and add several `tocbasic` features to `nomencl`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{scrhack}[2017/03/31]
\KOMAoptions{toc=indentunnumbered}
%\setuptoc{nls}{numbered}% you may try this as tocbasic feature example
%\pagestyle{headings}% you may try this to see the running head

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \printnomenclature
    \lipsum

    \addchap{Using \texttt{addchap}} 
    Test
    \chapter{Normal chapter}
    Test

    \nomenclature{$c$}{speed}

    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using other packages, but this is indeed a simple fix. +1. May I ask why there's a need to patch twice?

Comment: @Troy There is one `\addcontentsline` for classes without `\chapter` and one for classes with `\chapter` in `\thenomenclarure`. The second one is the last one, so two patches are not only recommended but needed.

Comment: What exactly does `setuptoc{nls}{numbered}` do? I tried looking up the `scrhack` package documentation but can't seem to find out anything about it. It doesn't seem to change anything when I compile it uncommented, though.

Comment: @Troy: It is an example for a `tocbasic` feature. Very simply: Try it after installation of the KOMA-Script prerelease. You will see it. For more information (or information without installation of the current prerelease) and additional features see the KOMA-Script manual, scrguien.pdf (English) or scrguide.pdf (German).

Comment: Ah interesting, I'm sorry I missed that.